# How to Create a User Profile in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Devise for user registration and authentication but want to have user profiles too, for example /user/john-doe with all the fields like Company Name, Phone Number etc which the person can add.

Is there any Rails way to get it done out of the box? any gem for this? if not, can someone give me some direction on how to do it?

Comment: Here's a one-liner for you :) `rails generate scaffold UserProfile company phone_number address`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Thanks, actually I already have the controller created as I am using Devise, but it has not created any user profiles like /usre/1 etc, so was hoping that I can get something pre built to speed up the work

Comment: Yeah, generate the scaffold. Also, I'd keep User and UserProfile separate. They have different purposes (in my view). User is for authentication, UserProfile is for, well, storing profile data.

Comment: Thanks, 2 questions, How to make sure userprofiles are only visible to only that user (I am assuming it needs access permissions) ? how to make the urls as example.com/user/Sergio instead of /user/1 ?

Comment: Please check the edit too, I am not able to connect the user with the user_profiles. when I am creating user profiles, the user_id column is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no gem to add company name, phone etc (at least I know :)), but normally what I do is,

I add the above columns to table, via a migration

Ex:  `add_column :users, :company_name, :string`

then I update the model accordingly

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, *:company_name*

end
```

then I run this command to copy the devise views

```
rails generate devise:views
```

then I update the corresponding view with new text_boxes etc..

HTH